# Insert binary data into huge binary file

Tags: python, file, binary

I have a very large archive file (~11 GB). I want to replace a file in that archive with a larger one ( I know the format i don't have any problem with that).
The question is, if there is any efficient way of doing this.

My current way is using this code:

```
f=open('big_archive','r+b') #open big archive


#Store data after the file
tail=open('temp_file_for_storing_rest_data','wb')
f.seek(correct_offset+old_file_size)
buf=1
while buf:
    buf=f.read(1024*1024*1024) #writing 1GB parts at a time
    tail.write(buf)
tail.close()

f.write(my_file_bytes) # write my file

#Append the tail back to the file
tail=open('temp_file_for_storing_rest_data','rb')
buf=1
while buf:
    buf=tail.read(1024*1024*1024) #reading 1GB parts at a time
    f.write(buf)
f.close()
```

Is there any way that i can avoid this disk read-write mess?

Edit: I am also getting some issues, when trying to increase the part size to 2GB. I get an overflowerror when the program tries to cast the size to C Long.

Comment: That's a lot of data, have you considered parallel processing ?

Comment: That's a lot of data, have you considered using a more appropriate storage method than flat files?

Comment: "I am also getting some issues, when trying to increase the part size to 2GB. I get an overflowerror when the program tries to cast the size to C Long." what kind of errors, where?

Comment: Paraller processing meaning opening multiple threads and grabbing data simultanously? As for the error with the C Long, thats what i get when i am trying to f.read(2*1024*1024*1024)

Comment: The problem is clearly IO bound so multiprocessing is not going to help here.

Comment: @DennisSakva i totally agree, so there is nothing i can do?

Comment: Probably not without changing the algorithm. Not in a simple way like multiprocessing any way.